# adding databases from wamp to xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, wampserver

I hope I didn't make a mistake,

I wanted to switch to xampp because it offers php5.5 and so I uninstalled wamp and installed xampp.

I was thinking that I could simply copy over the database files in mysql/data in wamp to the same directory in xampp and get my databases to show, buuut that wasn't the case.

Have I completely eff'd my databases?

The files in mysql/data// are of the .frm file type i.e. users.frm.

Comment: `.frm` are just the table definitions. they don't contain ANY Of the data. The data's kept in `.myd`, and indexes are in `.myi`

Comment: @MarcB Oh..i don't see those files in what has been graciously left over after the wamp uninstall. I guess I've lost them?

Comment: unless you were using innodb tables, which use different files, then yeah, your data's probably toast.

Comment: Yeah..the only other file type is .opt. Aw poo.

Comment: @MarcB I was using innodb, don't know why it wasn't saved though. What could be possible?

Comment: no idea. but if you were on innodb, then look for ibdata* files in the mysql repository. that'd be where your data is. The internal `mysql.*` database is still myisam, so users could very well be the standard mysql.users table, etc... your data MIGHT still be intact, IF the innodb data files are still present.

Comment: @MarcB hope at last! I do have a ibdata1 file, and it does look to contain my data. should i just copy it over to xampps mysql/data folder?

Comment: you'd lose any data you've put into the new install, but yeah, it should (maybe) just slip into place - you will have to stop/replace/restart mysql though.

Comment: @MarcB thanks, i'll do a bit of thinking and let u know

Comment: I'm just going to manually sql query my dbs again, it'll be a good refresher anyway. Note to anyone who would be seriously affected by this: export your databases using phpmyadmin BEFORE you uninstall your local setup

Answer (score 0):

You could just export the databases from one phpmyadmin and import them into the other.

Comment: I've already uninstalled wamp, so i don't think i have access to wamps phpmyadmin anymore (or do i?)